# Checkbox not aligning

Tags: css

So I have this code:

```
<div class ="pagecontent-checkbox">
        <form action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1">Smart Bridges<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="2">Smart Meters<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="3">Accounts Activated<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="4">Accounts Created<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">Always On Events<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">Monthly Efficiency Statistics<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">Efficiency Scores<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">Data Missing Statistics
        </form>
</div>
```

but it outputs like this:

[image]

How can I fix that?

I want it like this

[] Smart Bridges
[] Smart Meters
Etc..

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Checkbox, name, checkbox, name, enz

Comment: I changed it and used more sensible code and put the expected output at the end

Comment: The code you put in your edit works absolutely, perfectly fine on my Firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome, could it also be some styling issue that is already there on the page?

Comment: Most likely, because the raw code in your question works fine. What stylesheet do you use in addition?

Comment: A pretty big one to be honest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132507/discussion-between-right-leg-and-wouter).

Comment: looks like you have given a width to your input please show your css or we cannot help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the output you have, the output you expect, and the CSS you provided me:

```
input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 70%;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 92px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: rgba(111, 148, 178, 0.2);
    font-size: 1.083em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.38;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

First off, `display: block` is probably not what you want. Just remove this line.

Then, the following is your `input` description, where I left only what messes up everything:

```
input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 70%;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 92px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Basically, every line does something quite random. This code is not adapted at all for the form you want to have.

If this `input` has a reason to exist in your CSS code, then you should specify a `different` class to `<input>` tags in this particular form, and change your `input` in CSS to select every form but this one.

**HTML**

```
<input class="different">
```

**CSS**

```
input:not(.different) {
    /* 
    stuff
    */
}
```

This way, the form inputs with `different` class will receive the default style, which is what you want. Then you can improve this style for this particular form:

```
.different {
    /*
    stuff
    */
}
```

Comment: I had to do the input:not(.checkbox-input) on the class in the input itself <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="accounts-created" value="Accounts Created" class="checkbox-input"> that seems to remove the css but it definitely helped :)

Comment: @Wouter That's exactly what I wanted to write, but I got a bit confused... Edited my post. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you shared in [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132507/discussion-between-right-leg-and-wouter) it appears that there are CSS rules on any element with tag name *input*, which applies to the checkboxes.

The [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) rule (i.e. `width: 70%`) tells the checkboxes to take up 70% of the width of the parent container.

Also, the [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) rule (i.e. `height: 25px;`) makes each checkbox (well actually the area around it) taller, as does the *line-height* rule.

Additionally, the `display:block` doesn't seem to help, unless you want the text of checkbox below it. If the text should be on the same line.

The rule for [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) seems unnecessary so removing that rule (and [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)) can then be beneficial.

Stripping out many of those rules results in checkboxes laid out similar to your desired output. Take a look at the sample below - re-add styles as necessary.

```css
.pagecontent {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 65px 0 20px 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  overflow: visible;
}
.pagecontent-right-column {
    width: 24%;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

input {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: rgba(111, 148, 178, 0.2);
  font-size: 1.083em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="pagecontent">
    <div class="pagecontent-checkbox">
      <form action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1">Smart Bridges
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="2">Smart Meters
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="3">Accounts Activated
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="4">Accounts Created
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">Always On Events
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">Monthly Efficiency Statistics
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">Efficiency Scores
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">Data Missing Statistics
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="pagecontent-right-column">
      <!--{if {getUserMemberOfAdmin USERGROUPS=$management_user_groups} }-->
      <!--{*Selector for filter on labelpartner*}-->
      <!--{getAllLabelPartners}-->
      <div style="width: 80%; border: none; padding: 5px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <label for="Labelpartner_select">Filter charts on labelpartner</label>
        <!--{html_options id="Labelpartner_select" name="Labelpartner_select" options=$LabelpartnerList}-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```